# Error : "lvalue required as left operand of assignment"

Tags: c, recursion

```
void main()
{
    int sum=0;
    printf("%d",add(sum));
}

int add(int x)
{
    (x<=100) ? x=x+add(x+1) : x=0;
    return x;
}
```

In the function, I am trying to print sum of first 100 natural numbers using recursion.But I'm getting error as "lvalue required as left operand of assignment". Can anyone help me solve this error and explain the concept behind it?

Comment: Collect the answer in some variable and then return. Or else you can do tail recursion by taking everything into the function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're always setting `x`, put `x` on the left hand side. So instead of

```
(x<=100) ? x=x+add(x+1) : x=0;
```

use

```
x = (x <= 100) ? x + add(x + 1) : 0;
```

Alternately, since you're immediately returning that, you might just immediately return it:

```
return (x <= 100) ? x + add(x + 1) : 0;
```

---

The `()` in that expression are unnecessary, as well:

```
x = x <= 100 ? x + add(x + 1) : 0;
// or
return x <= 100 ? x + add(x + 1) : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using tail recursion you can do like this.

**DISCLAIMER might have some syntax error because I am not the C guy but the idea is not wait for return value to calculate the result**

```
int add(int ans ,int num){
if(num == 100)
return ans 
add(ans+num, num+1)
}

void main()
{
    int sum=0;
    printf("%d",add(sum, 0));
}
```